# Set Rotation based on device sensor overriding rotation lock

Tags: java, android, screen-rotation, google-mlkit

I have been trying to use the [ML Kit Vision Quickstart Sample App](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart) to develop a blink detection app.
For this, I have been using the **Face Detector** module with the **CameraX** library.
On installing the sample app on my Android phone, I found that rotating the device with Screen Rotation locked makes the app unable to detect faces, as expected.
I want to know how I should modify the code to override the Screen Rotation lock on the device, so that the app automatically rotates its orientation to detect faces.

Comment: please be more specific about your question. Show some codem examples. Please do not be offended and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks for your comment. I know the question is vague but when I had asked it, I had no leads on where and what code changes are required, so I couldn't put any code snippets in particular. No offense taken :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override the screen lock you may add the next tag to your target activity in the manifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```

Although this will only allow to rotate the activity regardless the screen lock. You still need to handle the orientation changes for the camera code. What I mean is that your camera lens is a fixed device and it doesn't rotate, therefore you need to handle image rotation by code.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, only instead of _sensor_ I used _fullSensor_. This was the page where I found all the options: [<activity> - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen)